# How to add Firebase ValueEventListner to multiple nodes at once and get notified of any data change accordingly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi actually I am new to Firebase and trying to implement feature like whatsapp stories.
What I have done is that i get a list of users to whom the user wants to share the story with, then
I add that story image to Firebase Storage and make an entry for the story in Firebase Database with all
necessary information.

Now for the other users whom i shared the story with need to observe the stories for all his contacts
who has shared story with him, so i need to make multiple ValueEventListner to observe for all the users who has shared story and exists in the contact list of this user.

Also i avoided the flat structure of database just to avoid extra code and also it would be very hard to implement the story delete feature with flat structure.

Here is my RealTime Database Screenshot.

[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQKli.jpg)

Is there any better way to implement this feature than what i did because i cant find any.

If any user logs in to my app then he should be able to get **all the stories of the people from his contact list who hasn't blocked him and added to him the "Invitees" List** ás shown in the code snippet.

**So the basic thing i wanna ask is if my approach is correct or i need some other pattern to get this feature like whatsapp, because listening to multiple ValueEventListner is kind of tricky part and seems not to be efficient for the client as well as for the database.**

Below is the code to publish story.

```
private void publishStory(){
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

    pd.setMessage("posting");
    pd.show();

    if(mImageUri !=null){
        StorageReference imageReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()+"-"+
                getFileExtension(mImageUri));

        storageTask = imageReference.putFile(mImageUri);
        storageTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task task) throws Exception {
                if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                return imageReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    myUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                    String myid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

                    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Story")
                            .child(myid);

                    String storyid = reference.push().getKey();
                    long timeend = System.currentTimeMillis()+86400000; // 1 day

                    HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                    hashMap.put("imageurl",myUrl);
                    hashMap.put("timestart", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                    hashMap.put("timeend",timeend);
                    hashMap.put("storyid",storyid);
                    hashMap.put("userid",myid);

                    reference.child(storyid).child(storyid).setValue(hashMap);

                    HashMap<String, Object> finalList = getHashMap(userList);

                    reference.child(storyid).child("Invitees").setValue(finalList);

                    pd.dismiss();

                    finish();
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(AddStoryActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(AddStoryActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        mImageUri = result.getUri();

        publishStory();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(AddStoryActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest editing the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect, so we can better see what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Added the publish story code @Doug Stevenson

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo It works preety well but the thing is that now after publishing the story the all of my contacts should be able to listen to this story added event and they need to get stories of all their contacts and for that we would need ValueEventListner on every contact's story node, but i am not sure how could i use multiple  ValueEventListners on all the contacts.      Adding ValueEventListner on "Story" node would be an overhead as it would update each time any user whether in or out of my contact list adds a story